# Custom display of images in my website

Tags: image, web

When you right-click on an image in firefox, and click on `Display image`, it displays it. And around it, there is a black background.

Can I put my own background image instead of the black background?

Comment: "When you right-click on an image in Firefox, it displays it" - how do you mean? The image wasn't displaying until the right-click?

Comment: @Utkanos Oops, I meant something else. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you're entering browser-level functionality that is beyond your control.

You wouldn't really want a user to have to resort to this anyway. Are you trying to display the image in isolation? In which case create your own 'image view' page or show it in a lightbox or something.

Comment: Thank you. I will wait a little bit (1 or 2 days) to see if there is someone who found a way to do it.